# How to get a range of columns as collection?

Tags: collections, multiple-columns, vbo, rpa, blueprism

EDIT: For context, I am trying to import a certain range of columns in an Excel sheet into a Blue Prism object as a collection.

So I've got a worksheet with columns from A to AM. When I get sheet as collection, blank columns named "Column1" to "Column10" (the first time) and "Column1" to "Column19" (the second time, note its 19 cols this time) mysteriously appear in the collection. No data is in these columns - no whitespace, nothing.

In order to prevent anything of the sort from messing up the collection cols, I'm looking for a way to get a range of *columns* as a collection, e.g. A - AM. The number of rows is undetermined, so the get range as collection action is not suitable. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I never really liked the default object to get range as collection because of that. You can create a new action in the Excel VBO object (do make sure to be careful with that since re-importing the default object will basically erase the action. I usually rename it as 'MS Excel VBO Customized' or something along those lines).

The way I would do it is as follows:

1. Open the 'MS Excel VBO' object and duplicate the page 'Get Worksheet Rage as Collection' and name it 'Get Worksheet Range as Collection New' (or anything you deem suitable):

   [image: Duplicated]
2. Edit the code stage: give it a new name (because code stages cannot have the same name in the same object) and change the inputs and code stages to match the following (I'm calling the new range as 'Address' here, but feel free to name it something else as long as you are consistent throughout):

   [image: Inputs]
   [image: Code]
3. Edit the start stage. You can delete the previous data items for Start Cell and End Cell and create one for Address:

   [image]
4. Publish and save the object. You can then use it from the object or process you are working on and use a range such as `A:AM`.

Comment: Also, I don't quite know why you are getting those extra columns in the first place. Sometimes excel does that (you can find out which one is considered the last cell by doing 'Ctrl+End' in the worksheet) and removes those extra columns if you delete them and save. Unfortunately, I don't see it as a viable solution, so here goes this suggested action.