# Is there a Blue Prism action to convert an entire excel column from long date to short date?

Tags: excel, automation, rpa, blueprism

In this instance, for this process, This cannot be done in Blue Prism via a collection as the spreadsheet is so large it takes too long to import the data set as a collection, even when pulling it in 'fast'.

**Has anyone came across a method to convert an entire column from long date to short date via Blue prism in excel?**

Eg: 12 October 2020 needs to be 12/10/2020

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If importing the entire table is too much for a collection, perhaps try importing the data column alone.
[How to get a range of columns as collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52378119/how-to-get-a-range-of-columns-as-collection)
Then you could loop through with a Calculation stage with

```
FormatDate([DateText], "dd/MM/yyyy")
```

If this is still too much for the collection you can perform the same action on each single cell, one at a time. You can build a loop that will read one cell, convert the date, and replace the data and then do it again on the next cell... for a given number of cells.
This will be slower but have none of the memory issues.

Finally, the fastest and most efficient solution would be to build a custom VBO that would perform the same steps as mentioned above, but in code.